# Redirect to jQuery Dialog after Action call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an asp.net MVC website (Visual Studio 2012, C#) that users can log into.  When they click the "Login" link, it opens a jQuery dialog which renders a partial login view.  I can get the dialog to post to the right action and controller but I need help with redirecting back to the dialog screen if the username/password combination is invalid.  I already have the error checking on the Submit button to check if a value exists in both before proceeding but need help with the other part.

I'll do my best to explain how the website is laid out:

**`_HeaderPartial View`**

```
<header id="header" class="style2">
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var jq = jQuery.noConflict(true);
        jq(document).ready(function ($) {

            $("#ViewLogin").live("click", function (e) {
                var url = $(this).attr('href');
                $("#login_panel").dialog({
                    title: 'Client Login',
                    closeOnEscape: true,
                    autoOpen: false,
                    resizable: false,
                    height: 350,
                    width: 400,
                    show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
                    modal: true,
                    draggable: true,
                    open: function (event, ui) {
                        $(this).load(url);

                    },
                    close: function (event, ui) {
                        $(this).dialog('destroy');
                    }
                });

                $("#login_panel").dialog('open');
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
    <div class="container">

        <!-- logo -->
        <h1 id="logo"><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
            <img src="~/images/small_logo.png" alt="Logo"></a></h1>

        <ul class="topnav navRight">
            <li>&nbsp;</li>

            @if (Session["LoggedIn"] == null || Convert.ToBoolean(Session["LoggedIn"])==false)
            {
                <li><a href="@Url.Action("ViewLogin", "Home")" id="ViewLogin">LOGIN</a></li>
            }
            else
            {
                <li><a href="@Url.Action("LogOut", "Home")">LOGOUT</a></li>
            }
        </ul>

    <other generic html markup omitted>
```

As you can see, the jQuery opens a dialog when the "Login" link is clicked, which is a simple div named "login_panel":

**`_Layout View`**

```
<div id="login_panel" style="display: none"></div>
```

**`_Login View`**

```
@model MyApp.LoginViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="login_panel">
    <div class="inner-container login-panel">
        <h4>SIGN IN TO ACCESS YOUR ACCOUNT</h4>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <div class="validation-text">
                <h5>@Html.ValidationSummary()</h5>
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Username)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Username, new { placeholder = "Username..." })
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Password)
                @Html.PasswordFor(x => x.Password, new { placeholder = "Password..." })
            </div>
            <br />
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">LOG IN</button>
            <div class="links"><a href="#" onclick="ppOpen('#forgot_panel', '350');">FORGOT YOUR USERNAME or PASSWORD?</a></div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

`LoginViewModel`

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is required.")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required.")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

And the **HomeController**

```
public ActionResult ViewLogin()
{
    return View("_Login");
}

public ActionResult LogOut()
{
    Session["LoggedIn"] = false;
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (ProPhysiqueContext db = new ProPhysiqueContext())
        {
            var user = db.Users
                            .Where(u => u.EmailAddress == model.Username &&
                                    u.WebPassword == model.Password).FirstOrDefault();

            if (user != null)
            {
                Session["LoggedIn"] = true;
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "ClientStats");
            }
        }
    }

    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Username or Password.");

    return PartialView("_Login", model);
}
```

So as you can see, I can get the dialog to render the `_Login` partial view correctly and it will post to the `Login` action on the Home controller.  I just can't figure out how to reopen the dialog from within the Action.  The way it is now, the website redirects to `_Login` partial view on the main page, not in a dialog.

ANY help is appreciated.

Comment: you might try using an ajax call like my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445816/ajax-beginform-refreshing-the-whole-page-in-mvc/19106739#19106739.  Also live has been deprecated so you should change .live('click'... to .on('click'

Answer (score 0):

How about using an Ajax form instead, that way you don't have to struggle with returning the view to the state it was in, i.e. opening the dialog.  To do this you'll need to change a few things:

1. Change your `Html.BeginForm` to an `Ajax.BeginForm` and set the `OnComplete` property to a javascript function that will be called, accepting a single parameter of the response.
2. Change your action method to return a `JsonResult` containing the redirect URL instead of the `RedirectToAction` result.
3. In your javascript function, depending on the response you will either replace the contents of the login form with the response or redirect to the URL.

Here are the relevant changes using your code.

**_Login View**

```
@* omitted for brevity *@
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Home", new AjaxOptions() { OnComplete = "complete" }))
{

}
```

**HomeController**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
    // omitted for brevity
    if (user != null)
    {
        Session["LoggedIn"] = true;
        return Json(new { url = Url.Action("Index", "ClientStats") });
    }
}
```

**HeaderPartial View**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jq = jQuery.noConflict(true);
    jq(document).ready(function ($) {
        // omitted for brevity
    });

    function complete(response) {
        try {
            var data = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
            if (data['url'])
                $(location).attr('href', data['url']);
        }
        catch (e) {
            $('#login_panel').html(response.responseText);
            // this is to reapply jQuery validation to dynamic content
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#login_panel');
        }
    }
</script>
```