# How to reload a Partial View in using Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

On my page, I have few boxes which are being generated at runtime, I want to do the validation if the boxes are "Empty" then user should not be able to Proceed and if the boxes contains some value then user can Proceed.

My validation is working fine with the help of JQuery (added below). But the ISSSUE is, as of now its working when I manually refresh my page, reason behind boxes which are generating are in a "PARTIAL VIEW". So now I want that partial view should reload/refresh

Below is the JQuery I have added to do the validation :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready (function () {
        if ($('.type').length == $('.type:empty').length){
            $("#stepAutomapConfirm").attr("disabled", true);
            $("#stepAutomapConfirm").addClass("disabled").removeClass("active");
        }
        else {
            $("#stepAutomapConfirm").attr("disabled", false);
            $("#stepAutomapConfirm").addClass("active").removeClass("disabled");
        }
    });

</script>
```

Here is the Fiddle of working JQuery: **http://jsfiddle.net/aasthatuteja/xJtAV/**,

**Note**: its working on fiddle as its but not in my Partial View
And below is the Action Controller:

```
[LoggingAspect]
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult AutomapInformation(int medCenterId, string medCenterSerialNumber, string viewName)
        {
            ProvisioningStepDto provisioningStepDto = ProvisioningHubProxy.Instance.GetOrCreateProvisioningStep(medCenterId, medCenterSerialNumber, WizardStep.AutomapInformation);
            AutomapInformationViewModel viewModel = null;
            try
            {
                var vaultInfo = ProvisioningHubProxy.Instance.GetMedCenterVault(medCenterSerialNumber);
                viewModel = new AutomapInformationViewModel
                    {
                MedCenterId = medCenterId,
                MedCenterSerialNumber = medCenterSerialNumber,
                Step = WizardStep.AutomapInformation,
                VaultInfo = vaultInfo
            };
            if (vaultInfo.Count != 0)
            {
                return PartialView(viewName, viewModel);
            }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogManager.Logger.Error(ex);
            }
            viewModel = new AutomapInformationViewModel
            {
                MedCenterId = medCenterId,
                MedCenterSerialNumber = medCenterSerialNumber,
                Step = WizardStep.AutomapInformation
            };
            return PartialView("StepErrorView", viewModel);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AutomapInformation(AutomapInformationViewModel viewModel)
        {
            LogManager.Logger.Info("ProvisioningController:AutomapInformation; [HttpPost] MedCenterId: ({0}), MedCenterSerialNumber: ({1})", viewModel.MedCenterId, viewModel.MedCenterSerialNumber);
            ProvisioningStepDto provisioningStepDto = ProvisioningHubProxy.Instance.GetProvisioningStep(viewModel.MedCenterSerialNumber, viewModel.Step);
            provisioningStepDto.ProvisionStepStatusId = (int)ProvisioningStepStatus.Complete;
            provisioningStepDto.VerifiedBy = "set current user";    //TODO: set the current user once authentication has been figured out
            ProvisioningHubProxy.Instance.UpdateProvisioningStep(provisioningStepDto, viewModel.MedCenterSerialNumber);

            return GetNextStep(viewModel.MedCenterId, viewModel.MedCenterSerialNumber, viewModel.Step);
        }
```

Below is the HTML Tag where the Table is being genrated on click of "Automap" button:

```
    <div id="vault_placeHolder">
       @VaultRenderer.BuildVaultHtmlProvision(Model.VaultInfo, "MedCenterVault", 510, 850, 0.5)
    </div>
<div role="button" class="marginTop50 marginBottom">
    <input type="button" id="stepAutomap" value="Automap" class="active" />
    <input type="button" id="stepAutomapBack" value="Back" class="active marginLeft50" />
    <input type="button" id="stepAutomapConfirm" value="Confirm & Proceed" class="active marginLeft10" />
</div>
```

**Note**: I also tried adding my JQuery function on click of the button but it didnt work as there also refresh requires. Also I tried adding reload(); in the end of my function with some setTime() but that also didnt help as the "boxes" within that timeframe were not being generated.

Let me know if you need any other information.

Please suggest!

Comment: Exactly why are you using partial view for this?

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445816/ajax-beginform-refreshing-the-whole-page-in-mvc/19106739#19106739