# MVC5 Ajax.BeginForm refresh whole page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax.beginform

Why is the form post not happening via ajax but instead is reloading to the new page?

My .js includes:

```
<script src="/App/JavaScript/Libraries/jquery-1.11.1-min.js"></script>
<script src="/App/JavaScript/Libraries/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/App/JavaScript/Libraries/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

My razor view:

```
<div id="login-partial-update">
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login",null, new AjaxOptions
{
    UpdateTargetId = "login-partial-update",
    HttpMethod = "POST"
}, new { id = "js-form-login" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new {placeholder = "Email address"})
    <div class="errormessage">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.Email)
    </div>
    @Html.PasswordFor(x => x.Password, new {placeholder = "Password"})
    <div class="errormessage">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Password)
    </div>
}
</div>
```

My controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginInputModel login)
{
     return PartialView("Widgets/Popups/_LoginInput", login);
}
```

Am I forgetting something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to include `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` file in your view to make `Ajax.BeginForm` to work.

Comment: where can I find it? I used nuget package: Microsoft Jquery Unobtrusive Validation

Comment: I found it, thanks. So which ones of the aboce included JS files can I delete (are no longer needed)?

Comment: @PoeHaH...don't delete those files because jquery validation file will help you for model validations..so just add this file...and don't forget to upvote and mark this as answer so that accepted answer help others also..

Comment: I have added the file but it's still not working (same problem). I have a new line in source: <script src="/App/JavaScript/Libraries/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>

Comment: just check the order in which you are using js files..on the top add jquery-1.11-min.js and after that add other files...

Comment: and make sure add these files at the end of the body

Comment: use ``@Url.Content()`` helper and pass relative url in it

Comment: @Kartikeya how can I add those scripts first in my _MainLayout and then add the other scripts of my views behind them?

Comment: just add file only once ... either include file in mainlayout or in view..don't include file twice...but keep in mind order in much you include js file will matter.@PoeHaH

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I can include all files in the main layout, but I have view specific .js files that depend on jQuery. If I include jquery at the bottom of my body tag in the mainlayout, how can I render my view .js files BEHIND them? 

Mainlayout has something like @RenderBody() and then @Scripts.Render(jquery)

Comment: Works now :) I was looking for @RenderSection

Answer (score 10):

This really tripped me up, and in searching for a solution - 99% of the responses all focused on previous versions of MVC and/or never mentioned the required NuGet packages. 
For some reason VS2013, does not include the "Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax" package when it builds a default MVC project. 
I found that the "jQuery validation" package was not needed either.

Once I installed that package, and added the script references the results were returned correctly to the target DIV.

To confirm, I am using:
 - VS2013 with MVC 4.5.1
 - jQuery 2.1.3
 - Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax 3.2.3

In BundleConfig.cs I decided to add a new bundle because of the confusion:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryunob").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*"));
```

And then applied it to all pages by referencing it in _Layout.cshtml:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryunob")
```

Answer (score 5):

**Add this key code to webconfig file**

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
 </appSettings>
```